# Guice field injection and TestNG

Tags: java, dependency-injection, testng, guice

When developing TestNG tests with Guice, a la this:

```
@Guice(modules=MyTestModule.class)
public class MyTestClass {
}
```

It's very easy to use field injection to declare the dependencies of the test class.  Now, suppose we have this:

```
@Guice(modules=MyTestModule.class)
public class MyTestClass {
    @Inject private Foo foo;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new SomeOtherModule());
    }
}
```

Because of field injection, if `SomeOtherModule` doesn't provide a binding for `Foo`, `myTest()` will fail due to `CreationException`, because it does not have the ability to create a `MyTestClass`, even if we do not intend for the test to create a `MyTestClass` with that injector.

Is there a way to express that intention, without changing into constructor injection of the `Foo`?  That is, is there a way to somehow make it not an error to create the injector, but do make it an error when trying to specifically provision a `MyTestClass`, without changing how `MyTestClass` is written?

Comment: What?  In that example, `MyTestModule` will be injecting `Foo`, not `SomeOtherModule`.

Comment: Right.  `MyTestModule`, governing the creation of `MyTestClass` by TestNG, will be created (and a `Foo` injected) fine.  However, the test itself, upon the creation of the injector local variable, will fail, due to `SomeOtherModule` lacking a binding for `Foo`.

Comment: No it won't?  `Guice.createInjector()` doesn't care about the class that calls it.  If you did `injector.injectMembers(this)` then that would fail, so don't do that.